# Not able to get console message from page.evaluate() to Page context (page.onConsoleMessage) in Phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

```
var page = require("webpage").create(),

     loginPage = "https://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/login/login.html";

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {

     console.log(msg);
};

page.open(loginPage);

page.onLoadFinished = function (status) {

    var url = page.url;
    console.log("Status:  " + status);
    console.log("Loaded:  " + url);
    pageload(url);
    page.render('url.png');

}

function pageload(url) {

    if (url == loginPage) {

        console.log("From loginPage");

        page.evaluate(function () {

            console.log("From pageload");

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it was probably a bug in the respective version of phantomjs, it works now, with version 1.9.8

Comment: I'm voting to close because the OP's problem doesn't occur in current versions of PhantomJS so it's not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

BUG!

a work around is assigning :

```
window.console.log = function(msg) { alert(msg) };
```

inside the page.evaluate

Then use :

```
page.onAlert = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};
```

to catch the alert

Answer (score -1):

for an obscure reason (Bug in WebKit or in PhantomJs), console.log does not works inside page.evaluate.

you should change you code in order to use console.info, console.warn or console.error.

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var loginPage = "https://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/login/login.html";

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
     console.log(msg);
};

page.open(loginPage);

page.onLoadFinished = function (status) {

    var url = page.url;
    console.log("Status:  " + status);
    console.log("Loaded:  " + url);
    pageload(url);
    page.render('url.png');
    phantom.exit(0);
}

function pageload(url) {

    if (url == loginPage) {
        console.log("From loginPage");
        page.evaluate(function () {
            console.info("From pageload");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your phantomjs setting does not disable executing javascript

```
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
```